# Last week date from Date()

Tags: java, date

AIM: I would like to get the last day of the week (Sunday) for the next 12 weeks into seperate Strings using Date()

I have the below which gives me the correct date format. I just need suggestions on the best solution to achieve my goal.

```
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
    Date date = new Date(0);
    System.out.println(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: @Todd What happened to your answer. It was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: FYI, Todd deleted [his Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15673270/642706). That Answer is now outmoded anyways. Much easier now with *java.time* classes. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018505/642706).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java's date system baffles me, but I think you want to do this:

1) Instead of making a Date, make a GregorianCalendar.

2) Calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY) to get the date for the sunday of this week.

3) In a for loop, add 7 days to the calendar twelve times. Do something on each loop (For instance, use getTime() to get a Date from the GregorianCalendar)

Comment: Thanks for that. I used Todds code example, but exactly the same answer as yours. Thanks Patashu

Comment: The old legacy date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java are indeed a baffling poorly-designed mess. Avoid them. Now entirely supplanted by the *java.time* classes. See [my Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48018505/642706).

Answer (score 1):

try

```
    GregorianCalendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    for (int i = 0; i < 12;) {
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);
        if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) == Calendar.SUNDAY) {
            System.out.println(DateFormat.getDateInstance().format(c.getTime()));
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI, the troublesome old date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`java.util.Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), and `GregorianCalendar` are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system), supplanted by the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes built into Java 8 & Java 9. See [Tutorial by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html).

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the last of the week is not always the same as Sunday since it is depending on which Locale you are using.

If you are using Java 8, the solution is pretty straightforward:

```
LocalDate firstJanuary = LocalDate.parse("01/01/2015",
                           DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy"));

//last day of the week
TemporalField fieldUS = WeekFields.of(Locale.US).dayOfWeek();
LocalDate lastDayOfWeek = firstJanuary.with(fieldUS,7);
System.out.println(lastDayOfWeek);

//sunday
LocalDate sunday = firstJanuary.with(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
System.out.println(sunday);
```

and to iterate to the weeks after, simply use:

```
sunday.plusWeeks(1);
```

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.now( 
    ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) 
)
.withNextOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY )
.plusWeeks( 1 )
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the java.time classes.

### Today

A time zone is crucial in determining a date. For any given moment, the date varies around the globe by zone. For example, a few minutes after midnight in [Paris France](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Europe/Paris) is a new day while still “yesterday” in [Montréal Québec](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal).

Specify a [proper time zone name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name) in the format of `continent/region`, such as [`America/Montreal`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/America/Montreal), [`Africa/Casablanca`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Africa/Casablanca), or `Pacific/Auckland`. Never use the 3-4 letter pseudo-zones such as `EST` or `IST` as they are *not* true time zones, not standardized, and not even unique(!).

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
```

The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

```
LocalDate today = LocalDate.now( z );
```

### Day of week

To find the next Sunday on or after today, use a [`TemporalAdjuster`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjuster.html) implementation found in the [`TemporalAdjusters`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAdjusters.html) class.

```
LocalDate nextOrSameSunday = today.withNextOrSame( DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
```

### Collection

Collect a dozen such sequential dates.

```
int countWeeks = 12 ;
List< LocalDate > sundays = new ArrayList<>( 12 ) ;
for( int i = 0 , i < countWeeks , i ++ ) {
    sundays.add( nextOrSameSunday.plusWeeks( i ) ) ;  // + 0, + 1, + 2, … , + 11.
}
```

Tip: Focus on working with representative data objects rather than mere Strings. When needed for display, loop your collection and generate strings with a call to `toString` or `format( DateTimeFormatter )`.

```
for( LocalDate ld : sundays ) {      // Loop each LocalDate in collection.
    String output = ld.toString() ;  // Generate a string in standard ISO 8601 format.
    …
}
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).